# SVN and getting started with Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, visual-studio, eclipse, svn

I have been working as a programmer for approx 15 years.  I have significant experience with 3 languages.  Object Pascal, C# and Python.  I just took a job (like two days ago) as a project manager for a Java project that has been written with the following tech stack.

Java EE
Eclipse Helios
Tomcat
Spring
MySQL
Code is in SVN

In preperation of starting the job, I read a couple of books on Java and played around with eclipse.  The language doesn't bother me at all - it's very similar to C#.  What I'm really struggling with now feels more like how to get started.

I've sync'd the code from the SVN repository, but literally am not sure how to proceed.  I think I'm use to having solution or a project file to "open" (like in Delphi and Visual Studio).  So, do I need to create a new workspace and "import" it from the file system?

I apologies for the newbie questions.  I just feel a bit lost getting started here.  Maybe someone that has recently come from a Visual Studio background can sympathize with me situation!  :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've had great success using subclipse with Eclipse. Once installed, you simply check out the project from the SVN repository.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends a bit on how your company's SVN is organized. For example, do they check in the Eclipse project settings, or do they expect you to check out the code and then generate Eclipse settings? Both are common approaches.

Assuming they have project settings in SVN, you should be able to just import them. You can either directly import from SVN as a new project (using the Eclipse new project wizard), or you can check out the code from SVN with an external tool (e.g. Tortoise) and then use Eclipse's import wizard to import the project. Go to `Import` -> `General` -> `Existing projects into workspace`, then browse to the location of your SVN working copy, and it should automatically pick up the Eclipse project(s) there.

**update** following up on your comments, let me expand a bit. Say, you check out a working copy from SVN using Tortoise, for example to `c:\foo`. You can then import any projects in that working copy into Eclipe, using the "Import existing projects into workspace" option I mentioned above. In the import wizard, you can choose if Eclipse should copy the actual code into its workspace directory, or should leave it where it is and just keep references. This is personal taste but I usually do *not* let Eclipse copy the code into its own workspace. That way, I can work with the code in Eclipse (and do SVN updates/commits directly from Eclipse), but also can quite easily do operations on my svn working copy outside Eclipse.

Comment: Ok...  another dumb question.  What are you talking about when you saying "project settings"?  The .classpath file and the .project file?

Comment: Yes, and also a .settings directory (though that is not always present, it contains things like project-specific code formatting rules, layout settings of your eclipse environment, etc).

Comment: yes.  The project that I sync'd down from SVN has a .classpath, .project file and a .settings folder.  So, let's say, I sync'd the project from svn to c:\foo.  Should I create a new work area at the same location and do an import?  Or a different location and import?

Comment: I'd say create a new workspace somewhere else (or just use Eclipse's default workspace, you don't usually need a new workspace for every project) and import. I've updated my answer with a bit more explanation, HTH.

Answer (score 0):

A workspace in Eclipse can contain multiple Projects.

When you open eclipse it has you select which workspace to use, and then you should be able to import the code into eclipse as a new Project. Have you tried using the Project Wizard?

Answer (score 0):

You won't find an exact equivalent of the .csproj file, the closest you get is the .project & .classpath files, between them eclipse has all the information to describe a project. If your svn checkout contains the .project file, you can directly import your project into eclipse using the Import Wizard. Else you can try creating a new project and pointing it to your svn checkout.